# Is my score randomly increasing?

Tags: bug

For some reason, this morning, I had a +2 score, but I hadn't accepted any answers to questions. Now my score is at 10,199 but I don't remember it being that earlier, and there are no notifications of score earned for anything as such regardless.

Is something wrong with my points tracking, or are points from other parts of the SE being added to mine here, or is something else going on?

Comment: You might get a +2 if someone previously downvoted a question or an answer and then they either changed their mind, or possibly the user was removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A question of yours that had -1 score was automatically deleted due to bad reception and long inactivity. With deletion, the -2 from the downvote were given back, as bumble surmised in comments already.

You can look things like these up when you choose "reputation" instead of "summary" on your landing profile page.